# Facebook Graph's /photos and /{photo-id} api not including "album" field (docs say it does)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The documentation says that `GET /{page-id}/photos` returns an *"An array of Photo objects."*,
see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos.

And the documentation for the photo object and `GET /{photo-id}` says it includes the album field,
see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo.

Though, I can't see that field in either `/{page-id}/photos` or `/{photo-id}`.

**Example:**

Take the first photo of http://graph.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/photos,
which is [this](https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/photos/a.444082318552.224990.19292868552/10151403325753553/?type=1). As you can see on the facebook page, this photo belongs to the "Profile Pictures" album,
but the response of http://graph.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/photos does not mention any album information.

Same for http://graph.facebook.com/10151403325753553, I don't see any `album` field or information.

Anybody an idea what is going on? This seems to be a bug either in the api or in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bug actually. Its just that not all the fields are returned by the API since there could be too many fields related to an API. Logical yeah..

But you can always request for the fields you want with `?fields=`

For the same examples you've used:

> Example 1:
>   
>   http://graph.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/photos?fields=images,link,picture,source,album
>
> Example 2:
>   
>   http://graph.facebook.com/10151403325753553?fields=images,link,picture,source,album

In the result you'll see the desired key `album`.

Comment: Oh wow, I missed that! I guess it would be good if facebook docs would make that feature more prominent and/or mark default fields as such. Thanks a lot!